# 404 on term taxonomy archive pagination only with some terms

Tags: terms, 404-error, custom-post-type-archives, paginate-links

On my site I've created a CPT with a hierarchical custom taxonomy:

```
// **CPT Args**
$args = [
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => false,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => ['slug' => 'documento'],
    'taxonomies'         => ['tipologia'],
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => ['title']
];

//**Taxonomy Args**
$args = [
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'rewrite'           => ['slug' => 'documenti'
    ],
];
```

Here the code for pagination:

```
echo paginate_links(
        [
            'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format'  => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages
        ]
    );
```

The strange issue is that the pagination works well with some terms:
Example:

> documenti/altri-documenti/comunicati/cs-2015/page/2/ <- it works *(it doesn't have child terms)*
>   documenti/altri-documenti/comunicati/page/2/ <- not works *(this term have children)* return 404
>   documenti/altri-documenti/memore/page/2/ <- it works *(this term have children)*
>   documenti/altri-documenti/memore/page/3/ <- not works *(this term have children)* return 404
>   documenti/formulari-moduli/page/2/ <- it works *(it doesn't have child terms)*

It seems like the issue is only with parent terms and not with the last child term.

> EDIT

The issue is also with permalinks disabled:

`/?tipologia=altri-documenti&paged=2` <- this does not work

Comment: You are in all propability running a custom query in place of the main query

Comment: In the taxonomy.php page I needed to add this: query_posts( array_merge( $args, $wp_query->query ) ); and adding some extra query args to the main query, but why for some terms works?What is your suggestion?removing the main query and add only a custom query?

Comment: **NEVER EVER** use `query_posts`, it breaks the main query, it is slow and totally stuffs up pagination. Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query to your needs. There are so many info about `pre_get_posts` on site, just use the site search

Comment: Thank you, using pre_get_posts instead of query_post fixed the issue...

Comment: My pleasure, glad you solved it. ;-). Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

user2660802 reports that the problem has been resolved thanks to using Pieter Goosen's suggestion of using `pre_get_posts` instead of `query_posts()`.

> `query_posts()` breaks the main query, it is slow, and totally stuffs
>   up pagination.